# flutter InteractiveViewer Wdget inside scroabble view

Tags: flutter

Hi am having a problem using InteractiveViewer widget on an image to zoom in and out because the Viewer in an scroabble page so it is hard to begin interaction with the viewer (my fingers scroll the page most of the time instead of interacting with the image) any tips how to solve this ?

I tried using the widget properties with no effect ,
am expecting it to start zooming when interact

Comment: Kindly add code snippet for better understand the issues

Comment: You can wrap with sizedbox for Image .(try)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.